# Arduinoにおける可視光による調歩同期式通信のデータビット幅

Tags: arduino, シリアル通信

Arduinoを使った可視光通信の実装をしているのですが、調歩同期式通信においてデータのビット幅を100msecから70msec等に狭めていくと、正しく受信することができません。
この理由を知りたいです。

ここで、ストップビットから次のデータのスタートビットまで(データの送信間隔)は1000msecに設定しています。

追記：
ご指摘があったのでより詳細な状況を説明します。
送信者はスタートビットから100msecで次々にビットを送り、受信者はスタートビットを確認すると、100msecで信号を読み取るとるようにしており、
そのビット間隔100msecを70msec等に狭めていくと、データが抜け落ちたりと正しく受信することができないということです。 (すなわち、送信者においてビット間の送信間隔を狭め、受信者においてもビットの検出間隔を同じだけ狭めるという意味合いです。)

また、この可視光通信の実装は、自然光の全くない暗室で行っています。

具体的なスケッチを簡単に述べると、送信側が送った可視光の明滅に対して、受信側においては可視光の強度をセンサによって数値化したものを、analogRead()で読み取り、その値が閾値を超えていれば"1"とし超えていなければ"0"としています。また、スタートビットを受信すると、データの読み取りをはじめ、データの読み取りごとにdelay(ビット間隔時間)を複数回行うことによって、ビット列を受信するようにしています。

Comment: 読者にとって（少なくともオイラにとって）状況説明が不足しすぎていてなにがなんだかわかりません。通信ってことは送信側と受信側が居るわけですが、ビットの幅を狭めるとはどっちの話をしています（送信側だけ、受信側だけ、両者とも？）可視光を使う以上は周囲の自然光はすべて雑音になりますが、それを除去できるハードウエア的工夫とか、ちゃんとしていますか？

Comment: すみません。
送信者はスタートビットから100msecで次々にビットを送り、受信者はスタートビットを確認すると、100msecで信号を読み取るとるようにしています。その100msecを70msec等に狭めていくという意味でした。

また、この通信自体、自然光の全くない暗室で行っています。

説明不足で申し訳ありません。

Comment: すなわち、ビット間隔を狭めるというのは、送信者と受信者の両者の話をしています。

Comment: RS232C等で言えばほんの少しボーレートを上げたら通信出来なくなったがそれは何故か？という質問に見えます。どんな仕様としてまとまっているかとか動かしているプログラムソースとかの情報を追記した方が良いでしょう。これら記事のどれかに関連していますか？[可視光通信 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%AF%E8%A6%96%E5%85%89%E9%80%9A%E4%BF%A1), [Arduinoを用いた...](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/inctkiyoupre/46/0/46_KJ00005074606/_pdf/-char/ja), [可視光LEDを用いた...](http://www.st.nanzan-u.ac.jp/info/gr-thesis/2015/okumura/pdf/12se258.pdf), [「カシツウ」](http://www.ne.senshu-u.ac.jp/~proj24-18/file.pdf), [ローリングシャッター効果...](https://ipsj.ixsq.nii.ac.jp/ej/?action=repository_uri&item_id=183736&file_id=1&file_no=1)

Comment: 他には例えばこの記事 [Arduino編その６ お部屋の明るさを数値化してみよう（PCへ送信）](http://marupeke296.com/EL_ard_No6_CdsCell2.html) の最後のように、最初から通信することを目的とするのではなく、間隔を短くした(速度を上げた)時にセンサーからどのようなデータを読み取っているのか、見える化してみるとかどうでしょう？

Comment: この手の話はソフトウエアを疑う前にハードウエアの動作をきっちり厳密に理解しておく必要があります。送信波形と受信波形をオシロスコープで測定した図とかないと質疑応答を続けるだけ無駄だったりしますので、まずはその辺から。この手のハードウエアの話は SO 向きな話題なのかどうかオイラにはわかりません。

Comment: to kunif さん
左様でございます。

Comment: bpsを上げると通信がうまくいかなくなるという言い方が一番わかりやすく正し買ったです。すいません。

また、「カシツウ」 http://www.ne.senshu-u.ac.jp/~proj24-18/file.pdf) と Arduinoを用いた可視光通信...(https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/inctkiyoupre/46/0/46_KJ00005074606/_pdf/-char/ja) が一番関連がありそうです。

Comment: to 774RRさん
申し訳ありません。
本日中に質問を取り下げさせていただきます。

Comment: いや取り下げる必要はないっつか。でも現状の質問本文だと情報が足らな過ぎて回答能わずだし、では回路図や波形データから何からすべてを提出してもらってどうこうだと仕事の代行依頼にしかならない感が。もっと「一問一答」になるような質問なら大いに歓迎されます（オイラもします）のでご考慮をお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

まずはオシロスコープを用意して、受信側の波形がどうなっているのか、というのを確認しましょう。
可視光を使っている、といってますが、送信側はどういう発光体を使って、受信側はどういうセンサを使っているのか全く記述がないところを見ると、ハードウエアについては全く頓着してなさそうに思えます。

当てずっぽで、推測で物事をすすめるのではなく、確実な観測事実を積み重ねていきましょう。
そうでないと、なにかわからないけど、だめでした、という結果にしかなりませんよ。

Answer (score 0):

送信側つまり発光側の光波形と、受信側つまり受光素子自体 (フォトトランジスタとか CdS とか) と復調装置の回路設計によっては、発光側で与えた波形と受光側で得られた波形の信号形状が違う（単に変形しているレベルではなくて全く似ても似つかないものになる）なんてのはごく普通にあります。なので 100msec = 10bit/sec で送受信できているシステムであっても実はハードウエア的・ソフトウエア的に余裕が全くなくて速度アップ 70msec = 14bit/sec を図ると破綻するなんてのはおかしな事態であるとは思いません。

> 理由を知りたい

実に様々な個所に様々な原因がありえて、現状の質問文では推測すらできないです。

というわけで現状の質問文からは「推定不能」としか答えられません。なのでエビデンス（証拠）を集めてください。設計者の意図と異なる動きをしている個所がわからないと直しようが無いです。

- 送信プログラム的にはこんな駆動波形を出しているつもり⇒本当にそうなっている証拠が必要
- 送信素子からこんな光が発しているはず⇒本当に以下略
- 受光素子からこんな信号が出ているはず
- マイコンの入力にこんな信号が来ているはず

そのためにはオシロスコープとかアナライザとか測定装置が必要ですし、使う側にも知識と経験が必要になるでしょう。

ハードウエア側は触れないということなら、現状の回路でどこまでできるかとか、現ソフトは現回路の挙動を理解して最適仕様なものを作れているかなどなど、検討できることはいくつもあるでしょう。でもいかんせん今の質問内容だと情報量が足らないです。

質問内の情報量を増せば答えられるかというと、そうとも限らなくて仕事の丸投げになりかねないです。範囲の広すぎる質問は SO ではクローズ対象になってしまいます。質問範囲を絞って１問１答が可能な範囲を探ってみてください。